# Does removing hexavalent chromium from a welded stainless steel part using phosphoric acid neutralise the CR(6) toxicity?

Tags: safety

We had a meeting today and talked about solving some issues improving the quality of life of our worker.

We were talking about hexavalent chromium. We already deal with the welding fumes, but as I understand the red pigment that is on a stainless weld is one form of chromium oxide that is the toxic CR(6). So our metal polisher would be affected too from this form.

One way we remove those oxides from the stainless before polishing is using a surfox machine. Essentially, it is a mixture of phosphoric acid that is used as an electrolyte with the application of an electric current.

Now that you have the background, my question is: does the use of this method neutralise the toxicity of the CR(6) transforming it into something else that is not toxic or it simply creates something like a salt containing the same toxic property as the CR(6) itself?

It would help us know how to deal with the issue properly for our workers.

Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: Chromium is present throughout the steel, and what you propose only impacts the surface. When you make a weld pool, you will bring chromium into the melt as you melt the steel.

Comment: Do you propose using the phosphoric acid bath *after* welding? In that case, the comment of @JonCuster does *not* apply -- the Cr deep inside the steel will *not* migrate to the surface after the weld is completed. *Welders* would still need protection from fumes, but not *polishers*, **if** the bath is effective in reducing Cr(VI). However, you'd need to have both the used bath and the metal surface analyzed to see how much Cr(VI) is present.

Comment: Yes we are using the phosphoric acid after the weld is done to remove the oxide layer produced when the metal was still hot and and the argon gaz protection is removed so the hot metal was in contact with oxygen. From my undertanding the hexavalent chromium can be produce by this oxidation reaction. The color differ depending on the temperature of the stainless parts when it come into contact with oxygen.

Comment: But the main issue i want to know is if the product that is created from the phosphoric acid when it dissolve the chromium oxide, what i presume is CR(6), is not toxic or if it created just another toxic salt in itself. This way we have to find a way to treat all that is around the machine as toxic too and when it dry it could produce a toxic dust that could go everywhere in the shop when we open doors.

Comment: You mentioned that your machine passes an electric current through the solution. Hexavalent chromium is reduced to chromium (III) by the application of an electric current (Sidenote, this is investigated as a method of treating Cr (VI)-containated wastewater). Sadly, I don't know how to calculate whether all of the chromium (VI) is reduced using the process you described or if a substantial amount still remains in solution.

Comment: An acid wash removes basic oxides such as Cr2O3 and Iron oxides and possibly CrO2 [it disproportionates] not chromic acid, CrO3, that happens to be soluble in water. H2PO4 does not reduce anything.

Comment: Ok so thank you all for your input. From what i've read in the last comments, the acid wash does not modify the CR(6) that is present and it stay in the residual solution. BUT passing a current through the solution could reduce the CR(6) to CR(3), but there is no way to quantify if CR(6) could remain. As CR(6) is a known carcinogen and have a pletora of health effect, CR(3) is safer, but is still dangerous. So the only option that is left to me is take a sample to a lab to measure the composition and ask for a proper way to neutralise/dispose of it. Thank you again for your help!